# android: add a textview about map marker for ALL markers

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

Our designer has provided me with a custom icon to display on maps. Our MapView will display several icons of those at the same time.

The tricky part: every icon should have a text above it displaying what it is - and all icons should show this text always simultaneously.

So I know that there is .showInfoWindow(), but that only shows one window at a time and only onclick.

I found this SO post:
[Map Markers with text in Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837510/map-markers-with-text-in-google-maps-android-api-v2?rq=1)

but that's using google's library and it only is able to use a colored rectangle as a text holder, not, as in my case, an icon AND the text above.

Searching, I found several ideas but none seems to work. My last attempt:

```
 LatLng pos = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
                paint.setTextSize(11));
                canvas.drawText(item.getString("name"), 10, -20, paint);

                Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(pos)
                                .title(item.getString("name"))
                                .icon(
                                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm)
                                        )

                );
```

But I still can only see the icon and no text.

Comment: what is 10 and -20 in drawText?  read drawText() docs in order to know how it works

Comment: I think your last attempt should work, it has to be padding and the position

Comment: @pskink right, my thinking was wrong here - changed to 10, 20. kaho indeed it works, but not ok. I get some text above the marker icon, but it is barely readable - it has no background color. I'd need to set a colored background so that the text is readable, but no idea how to do that. Also, the text is currently cut to the width of the icon. It should expand....

Answer (score 0):

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
 markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);